# Сохранение/Чтение пользовательских настроек html таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>BirthDate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Если пользователь например захочет скрыть столбец "FirstName", сохранить ее и при последующем запуске сервиса получить сохраненную конфигурацию своей таблицы, а не все поля. Как и при помощи чего это можно реализовать?

**Update:** Хранить конфигурацию необходимо на сервере, так как подразумевается, что пользователь будет иметь несколько точек входа.

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит обратить внимание на localeStorage (это хранилище данных на стороне клиента).

запись:

```
localStorage.setItem("tr1", "hide");
localStorage.setItem("tr2", "show");
```

чтение:

```
var status[0] = localStorage.getItem("tr1");
var status[1] = localStorage.getItem("tr2");
```

А дальше можете добавить строкам класс hide/show

Comment: Я так понимаю это актуально только для одного ПК, а если пользователь захочет войти с другого, то выходит  - настройки не будут сохранены.

Comment: Если пользователь захочет войти с другого пк, значит у вас есть процедура авторизации, значит вы можете хранить пользовательские настройки в БД и выдавать их на клиент после авторизации.

Comment: Так в том то и вопрос, как и при помощи чего? Про авторизацию и бд я и так знаю.